# How to select a random variable(String/Name of HTML file) in chrome extension's manifest.json

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, manifest.json

I am trying to make a chrome extension where I want to select a random page from 10 pages and set it as "new tab". How can I do that cause I cant use js?

I am trying to do something like this

"newtab": "%VAR%/index.html"

%VAR% is selected randomly from an array of 10 elements.

Comment: *put a specific page as a new tab and within this redirects the page to the other*

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.